# Distribution of residues of integers coprime to $n$, modulo another integer also coprime to $n$

Tags: number-theory

[Project Euler problem 202](https://projecteuler.net/problem=202) reduces to the following question:

> Let $n$ be some large number that's not a multiple of $3$ (the Project Euler problem's test case has $n = 6\,008\,819\,575$). How many integers $m \in \{1, \ldots, n-1\}$ are there such that $m + n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $\gcd(m, n) = 1$?

Intuitively, the answer should be *about* $\varphi(n)/3$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function: there shouldn't be any relationship noticeable in the long run between residues modulo $3$ and modulo the divisors of $n$ (and, of course, the interval $[1, 3n]$ should have the same number of integers coprime to $n$ in each of the three residue classes modulo $3$). And taking $\varphi(n)/3$ for the Project Euler test case gives an answer that is $42 \frac{2}{3}$ off, small relative to $n$ but not exact. Is there a bound or, better yet, an easily computable formula for the difference between $\varphi(n)/d$ and the number of positive integers less than and coprime to $n$ with a certain residue modulo $d$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's recall a standard calculation involving the [Möbius $\mu$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Properties):
\begin{align*}
\phi(n) = \sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ \gcd(m,n)=1}} 1 &= \sum_{1\le m\le n} \sum_{d\mid\gcd(m,n)} \mu(d) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) \sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ d\mid m}} 1.
\end{align*}
We can combine this with a way of detecting multiples of $3$: setting $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/3}$, we have
$$
\frac13 \sum_{j=0}^2 \zeta^{kj} = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } 3 \text{ divides } k, \\ 0,&\text{if } 3\text{ does not divide } k.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ \gcd(m,n)=1 \\ 3\text{ divides } m+n}} 1 = \sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ \gcd(m,n)=1}} \frac13 \sum_{j=0}^2 \zeta^{j(m+n)} &= \frac13 \sum_{j=0}^2 \zeta^{jn} \sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ \gcd(m,n)=1}} \zeta^{jm} \\
&= \frac13 \sum_{j=0}^2 \zeta^{jn} \sum_{1\le m\le n} \zeta^{jm}\sum_{d\mid\gcd(m,n)} \mu(d) \\
&= \frac13 \sum_{j=0}^2 \zeta^{jn} \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) \sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ d\mid m}} \zeta^{jm} \\
&= \frac13 \bigg( \phi(n) + 2 \Re \Big( \zeta^n \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) \sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ d\mid m}} \zeta^m \Big) \bigg),
\end{align*}
since the $j=0$ term becomes the right-hand side of the first identity above, while the $j=2$ term is the complex conjugate of the $j=1$ term since $\zeta^2=\overline\zeta$.

Now, notice that $d$ is never a multiple of $3$ since $3$ doesn't divide $n$. Consequently, the inner sum $\sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ d\mid m}} \zeta^m = \sum_{1\le\ell\le m/d} \zeta^{d\ell}$ is a nontrivial geometric series of third roots of unity! Its value is either $0$, $\zeta$, $\overline\zeta$, or $-1$. In particular, its modulus (hence its real part) is at most $1$. Since $|\zeta^n|=1$ and $|\mu(d)|\le1$ as well, it follows from the triangle inequality that
$$
\bigg| \sum_{\substack{1\le m\le n \\ \gcd(m,n)=1 \\ 3\text{ divides } m+n}} 1 - \frac{\phi(n)}3 \bigg| \le 2\sum_{d\mid n} 1 = 2\tau(n),
$$
and so the error is at most twice the number of positive divisors of $n$. It wouldn't be too hard to convert the right-hand side of this long computation into an exact formula if desired—each term would depend only on $\mu(d)$ and the residue classes of $n$ and $d$ modulo $3$.

What we are doing here, in a by-hand manner, is using [(additive) characters of cyclic groups](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eacwood/files/notes/cyclicgroup.pdf) to detect which $m$ lie in a particular residue class modulo $3$; replacing the $3$ with $d$ and using the more general additive characters (essentially replacing $e^{2\pi i/3}$ above with $e^{2\pi i/d}$) would allow one to approach the more general question.